# Lookup column from another list according to 2 respective list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

Experts,I already created a workflow using SharePoint designer 2013 that will sent email to (**Email id get from list 4 beta** ) field and cc the email to( **Email id cc get from list 5 beta**  field).

The workflow works if i fill up the 2 column name **Email id get from list 4 beta** and **Email id cc get from list 5 beta** ,When the Trigger column change from don't send email to sent email it will sent the email.

My intention is
EXAMPLE: when a file is added and ,(if the GM=MEA & DSC=EU) it will sent email to (Mhalmi@gmail.com) and cc the email to (AKhalid@gmail.com) as shown in the 1st picture. But right now. I want it to automatically get BOTH the email id from list 4 beta and list 5 beta.

The issue here are, I want to **lookup both of the column email id** from their **respective** list (**from list 4 beta and list 5 beta**). List 4 beta is contain the email ID for me **to** sent, while list 5 beta contain email for me to **cc** the email.There are 2 list (picture below). So this system will recognise itself to email to whom and to cc to whom **automatically** the moment there know the content of (GM and DSC column)

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct you cannot do that using the build in actions in the workflow. They only support matching one lookup column. However you can do it by utilising the REST api.

It can be a little daunting at first, but it's not too bad once you get into it. One note though is you need to do your own error handling as the workflow will complete regardless of the outcome of the webservice.

The steps involved would be:

1. Get the first item that matches both your lookup columns
2. Verify that you did indeed get any items in the response content
3. If no items are returned do your error handling
4. If any items are returned grab the email from the response from the response content

I havn't got time to write a detailed guide on how to do it, but you should be able to get started by following this guide: https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2017/06/25/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflows-and-get-rest-api/

Comment: thanks for the reply, I just notice there is a mistake in my question. I have edit the question. thanks sir. I ll check the link